# Best way to have Active-Active mongo setup in 2 data center scenario?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

In case when we have 2 data centers and want to have an Active-Active setup with 2 shards, what is the best way to achieve this? Let's say setup looks something like this:
[Active-Active 2 DC setup with 2 shards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRlUi.jpg)

Here if one data center goes down, then other data center will have only 2 machines per shard and automatic leader election won't happen (Mongo required struck >50% machines for leader election). It will require manual intervention for the leader election to work again in read-write mode and until then it will be read-only mode. Can we somehow use some other setup or make use of an **arbiter** to make an automatic leader election in case one DC goes down?